# SQL: Cannot Select Database

Tags: php, sql

When I try to create the users table, I get the following error message:

> Error creating table: No database selected

I've tried `SELECT`, `USE` and creating new connections, but I can't seem to connect to the secure_login database I have created. Maybe I've been formatting it wrong, I'm unsure. I know I have not included an attempt to select a database, this is for the reason that everything I'm doing just does not seem to work.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected to server successfully" . "</br>";
    // CREATE SECURE LOGIN
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS secure_login";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "secure_login functional" . "</br>";
        //CREATE USERS TABLE;
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
            username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            password CHAR(128) NOT NULL
        )";
        //MAKE ADMIN USER
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password)
        VALUES ('1', 'admin', 'test@test.com', 'password')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Table users functional" . "</br>";
        } 
        else {
            echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error . "</br>";
        } 
    } 
    else {
        echo "secure_login not functional: " . $conn->error . "</br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try calling "$sql = 'use '. database_name; before the creation of the table.

Comment: Just as the error states, you need to select the database after you created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an working example .. i have just made a new connection after database is created .. with the newly created database. May be there are other alternative ways . but this is working for me ..

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected to server successfully" . "</br>";
    // CREATE SECURE LOGIN
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS secure_login";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "secure_login functional" . "</br>";
        $dbname= "secure_login";
        $newConnection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
        //CREATE USERS TABLE;
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
            username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            password CHAR(128) NOT NULL
        )";
        if ( $newConnection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Table users functional" . "</br>";
        } 
        else {
            echo "Error creating table: " .  $newConnection->error . "</br>";
        } 
        //MAKE ADMIN USER
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password)
        VALUES ('1', 'admin', 'test@test.com', 'password')";
        if ( $newConnection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "inserted successsfully" . "</br>";
        } 
        else {
            echo "Error Inserting: " .  $newConnection->error . "</br>";
        } 
    } 
    else {
        echo "secure_login not functional: " .  $newConnection->error . "</br>";
    }
?>
```

**Output**

Connected to server successfully

secure_login functional

Table users functional

inserted successsfully

Comment: glad it works.
if you think this is helpful please upvote and mark as correct it will help others on future .

Answer (score 3):

```
 $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS secure_login";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {


    // Start Using it at this point :)
```

You have created your new database but have not told mysqli to use this for further queries, so your SELECT query has no database to select from.

You can simply do

```
$conn->select_db("secure_login");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply need to add a select statement after you've created the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can call before //CREATE USERS TABLE:

```
mysqli_select_db($conn,"secure_login");
```